# Cannot convert dbconnection to sqlconnection

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have created a generic method which will work with all database like sql server,mysql and oracle and execute my sql query and return datatable.

```
private Datatable GetData(string connectionString,string query
{
    if (model.RdbmsType =="Mysql")
    {
         return ExecuteSqlQuery<MySqlConnection>(connectionString,query);
    }
    else if(model.RdbmsType == "SqlServer")
    {
       return ExecuteSqlQuery<SqlConnection>(connectionString,query);
    }
    else // for oracle
    {
       // code for oracle
    }

}

private Datatable ExecuteSqlQuery<T>(string connectionString, string sqlQuery) where T : DbConnection, new()
{
    using (DbConnection connection = new T())
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection); //Error : Cannot convert dbconnection to sqlconnection
        var queryData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

**Error on this below line :**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection); //Error : Cannot convert dbconnection to sqlconnection
```

I even tried like below :

```
DbCommand cmd1 = new DbCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
```

But as Dbcommand is abstract class i cant do above.

So how do i make my ExecuteSqlquery method to work with all sql server,mysql and oracle??

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your posts - you've written over 250 posts, so by now I'm sure you know *how* to use the preview, and unindent code appropriately etc... please respect other people's time by taking the trouble to make your question as readbale as it can be.

Comment: @JonSkeet:I am really sorry if thats the case but i have use ctrl + k to format my code but i dont know how to do indentation

Comment: Then you should learn about it now. Read the help. If nothing else, I assume you know how to use the space and delete keys - they're all you really need. But if you highlight a block of text that's already indented, and press ctrl-k, that will outdent it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, when you call `new SqlCommand()`, that will *only* work with a `SqlConnection`. It's not going to work for `MySqlConnection`, or for anything from Oracle etc. `SqlCommand` is tightly coupled to `SqlConnection`.

So either you need a `Func<string, T, DbCommand>` as well (that would call the `SqlCommand` constructor, or similar) or just separate out your methods instead of it being generic - have separate `ExecuteSqlQuery`, `ExecuteOracleQuery` etc methods.

Or you could just make the command type another generic type parameter, and have:

```
private Datatable ExecuteSqlQuery<TConnection, TCommand>(string connectionString, string sqlQuery)
    where TConnection : DbConnection, new()
    where TCommand : DbCommand, new() 
{
    using (DbConnection connection = new TConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        TCommand cmd = new TCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        var queryData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

Then you'd call it with:

```
return ExecuteSqlQuery<SqlConnection, SqlCommand>(connectionString, query);
```

(etc).

Alternatively, look at [`DbProviderFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory(v=vs.110).aspx), which is designed for this sort of scenario as far as I can tell.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but is it a good idea to seperate out my method for each of the database type(sql server,mysql) but that would lead to code duplication.Isnt it?

Comment: @Learning: Well I've given you three alternatives... (providing a delegate to construct a command from a connection and a query, or using `DbProviderFactory`, or using separate methods). It's up to you to weigh up which one you think is best for you.

Comment: Here is an example of using the DbProviderFactory with different providers: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55890/Don-t-hard-code-your-DataProviders

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the answer :)